# setBackgroundColor() appears not to work

Tags: android

I have some rather simple code. I go through each item within a layoutBIds array and set the color of the background accordingly.

setBackgroundColor works perfectly well on bidLayouts.

But when I call

```
BidDriverPrice.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Chartreuse));
```

It does not work for that view. I have tried setBackgroundResource and even single similar question from the first three pages of Google search result so I am sure I am missing something.

```
for (int i = 0; i < layoutBids.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = layoutBids.getChildAt(i);
        RelativeLayout bidLayouts = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.bidlayout);
        final TextView BidDriverPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.BidDriverPrice);
        final TextView BidDriverMins = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.BidDriverPrice1);
        if (rgxBidOffer.size() != 0) {

            if (rgxBidOffer.get(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())).seconds > 0) {
                bidLayouts.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Variables.context, R.color.orange));
            } else {
                bidLayouts.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Variables.context, R.color.White));
            }

            if (autoBidMode == Setting.AUTO_BID_MODE_CHEAPEST) {
                for (TDriverBids rgxBids2 : rgxBidOffer) {
                    if (rgxBids2.amICheapest) {
                        autoBid = rgxBidOffer.get(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString()));
                        BidDriverPrice.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Chartreuse));
                    } else {
                        BidDriverPrice.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
                    }

                }
            } else if (autoBidMode == Setting.AUTO_BID_MODE_NEAREST) {
                for (TDriverBids rgxBids2 : rgxBidOffer) {
                    if (rgxBids2.amINearest) {
                        autoBid = rgxBidOffer.get(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString()));
                        BidDriverMins.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Chartreuse));
                    } else {
                        BidDriverMins.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you change the background color in the layout xml itself, does it have any effect?

Comment: Try it using some different color like `getResources().getColor(android.R.color.red)` is working or not

Comment: Tried using android.R.color.holo_red_dark... Still not working - Good suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

you could try calling `setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);`
after you set the background color.